# Solar: Reason For Joining Batteries/Solar Panels in Series

Tags: battery-charging, solar-cell, series

I understand the concept of what happens when you do, but I do not understand the reason behind why some set-up require to double the voltage on the batteries, since the point is to store as much AH as possible. Is it for special devices that takes 12v or more, or it has something to do with better dealing with inverters?

Answer (score 2):

It's a tradeoff between voltage and current.  If you put the batteries in parallel, then you have a higher current, but lower voltage.  In this case, you need thicker cables to connect to the batteries, or put up with more power loss - the power lost is proportional to the SQUARE of the current.

Also, the semiconductor devices in the charging circuit will typically have a fixed voltage drop across them when they are conducting.  Therefore, if you can reduce the current, you reduce the power lost, and improve efficiency.  Higher-voltage semiconductors will have a higher voltage drop, but not enough to counteract the savings from the reduction in current.

Furthermore, there are other advantages depending on what is being driven.  Remember that the battery voltage is going to fluctuate depending on the charge state of the batteries.  If you need a steady, regulated 12V output, then it is much easier to provide this from a 24V-ish supply than a 12V-ish supply - stepping down DC voltage is easier (and therefore more efficient) than stepping up.  As the batteries get into a lower discharge state, the output regulation will find it easier with the 24V-nominal supply.

Comment: From what I understand, if I parallel two 12v 100AH batteries, I would have to use thicker cable and running longer cables the more power I loss, much more since it's a thick cable?

Comment: Not quite.  When putting them in series, the current is higher, and therefore, you lose more power UNLESS you give it a thicker cable.  For example, if your batteries are 12V@1A each, then in parallel you've got 2A running down the cable compared to 1A with the batteries in series.  Now, if your cable has a resistance of 1 Ohm, then P=I^2R means that you're losing 4 W through the cable with batteries in series, and only 1W through the cable with the batteries in parallel.  If you use thicker cable with 0.25 Ohm resistance, then your power loss drops back to 1W.